# Center of Mass of objects with infinite length?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Suppose you have $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

And you have that shape, find the center of mass of $f(x)$ in $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$

Is it possible considering $f(x)$ is an even function?

Comment: Because it is an even function and therefor symmetric, the $x$ component of the center of mass (assuming it is of uniform density) would be 0. For $y$ it would be more complicated though.

Comment: One thing is for certain , if center of mass exists it would be somewhere around x axis